# Which option is good in terms of software design?

Tags: c#, design, interfaces, class, polymorphism

I have one request interface `IRequest` and two classes `ClientAddress` and `ClientOrder` are implementing it. The same design is followed for Response with inteface `IResponse` and classes `ClientAddressResponse` and `ClientOrderResponse`.

I have tried to do it 2 ways but I am not sure which is better way

1. With Explicit type casting by assigning class object to interface.
2. By using classes object and variable

See here:

```
public interface IRequest
{
    string ClientId { get; set; }
}

public class ClientAddress : IRequest
{
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string AppId { get; set; }
}

public class ClientOrder : IRequest
{
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string FromDate { get; set; }
    public string ToDate { get; set; }
    //other properties
}

public interface IResponse
{
    string ClientName { get; set; }
}

public class ClientAddressResponse : IResponse
{
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}

public class ClientOrderResponse : IResponse
{
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public List<Orders> OrderList { get; set; }
    //other properties
}

public class DAL
{
    public IResponse GetAddress(IRequest req)
    {
        //return client address 
    }
    public IResponse GetOrderList(IRequest req)
    {
        //return order list 
    }
}
```

### Variant 1

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IRequest req1 = new ClientAddress();
        req1.ClientId = 1;
        ((ClientAddress)req1).AppId = "abcd";
        DAL d = new DAL();
        IResponse res1 = d.GetAddress(req1);

        IRequest req2 = new ClientOrder();
        req2.ClientId = 1;
        ((ClientOrder)req2).FromDate = "2019/01/01";
        ((ClientOrder)req2).ToDate = "2019/01/15";
        IResponse res2 = d.GetOrderList(req2);
    }
}
```

### Variant 2

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClientAddress req1 = new ClientAddress();
        req1.ClientId = 1;
        req1.AppId = "abcd";
        DAL d = new DAL();
        IResponse res1 = d.GetAddress(req1);

        ClientOrder req2 = new ClientOrder();
        req2.ClientId = 1;
        req2.FromDate = "2019/01/01";
        req2.ToDate = "2019/01/15";
        IResponse res2 = d.GetOrderList(req2);
    }
}
```

Please guide me which design is good/bad and why we should use/avoid it or is there any other way to achieve the same.

Comment: Well, you should clearly not be casting a local variable to its known type. Downcasting is best avoided generally.

Comment: Please try and edit the question to have a more informative title; just about every question on this site could be under the current title!

Comment: Am I glossing over something or is this question essentially "should I hard cast or not?"

Answer (score 3):

Based on just your sample program, there is no benefit to having interfaces since you are trying to access implementation-specific fields such as `AppId` and `FromDate`. You should avoid casting and just use the concrete type for this purpose.

Interfaces become useful when you want clients to handle different types of objects in a similar manner through the common interface. For example, you could log the `ClientId` of all incoming requests regardless of their actual type:

```
public void LogRequest(IRequest request) {
  Console.WriteLine("Received request from client " + request.ClientId);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are problems with the approach you are taking. For example, consider the `DAL` class:

public class DAL
    {
        public IResponse GetAddress(IRequest req)
        {
            //return client address 
        }
        public IResponse GetOrderList(IRequest req)
        {
            //return order list 
        }
    }

`GetOrderList` states it takes an `IRequest`. I'm guessing though that if I passed it an instance of `ClientAddress`, it wouldn't work. As such, it doesn't want an `IRequest`, it wants a `ClientOrder`. So you are setting your code up to fail by not specifying that type.

Likewise, that method returns an `IResponse`, but I'd need to cast it to `ClientOrderResponse` to actually get at the data returned. So again, it should be returning a `ClientOrderResponse`.

You *appear* to be trying to use interfaces in the belief that you *should* use interfaces, but those interfaces serve no useful purpose in your example code and actually cause harm. So get rid of them and simplify the code down to:

```
public class ClientAddress
{
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string AppId { get; set; }
}

public class ClientOrder
{
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string FromDate { get; set; }
    public string ToDate { get; set; }
    //other properties
}
public class ClientAddressResponse
{
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}

public class ClientOrderResponse
{
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public List<Orders> OrderList { get; set; }
    //other properties
}

public class DAL
{
    public ClientAddressResponse GetAddress(ClientAddress req)
    {
        //return client address 
    }
    public ClientOrderResponse GetOrderList(ClientOrder req)
    {
        //return order list 
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var req1 = new ClientAddress
        {
            ClientId = "1",
            AppId = "abcd"
        };
        DAL d = new DAL();
        var res1 = d.GetAddress(req1);

        var req2 = new ClientOrder
        {
            ClientId = "1",
            FromDate = "2019/01/01",
            ToDate = "2019/01/15"
        };
        var res2 = d.GetOrderList(req2);
    }
}
```

The only class in your example that would benefit from having an interface is the one you didn't apply an interface to: `DAL`. Since it will be hard-coded to directly access some data store, then being able to mock it for eg unit tests is essential. So have that implement `IDAL` and have all of your application, save for `Main` refer only to `IDAL`, not `DAL` directly.